# Does google developer console mobile emulation work?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome-devtools

I guess this may be kind of a stupid question. It's just that according to the tool, my page is effed on several non-iOS devices, and I'm not sure why that would be.

If you have a second, take at look at this page (which was designed for iPhone 5, since that's what I have) using Google's mobile emulator, set to the Samsung Galaxy S4 setting:

http://www.radionowheremusic.com/mobiletest.html

On my machine, the content is off-screen to the right, and you have to scroll over to see it. Is that how it looks to everyone out there?

If anyone could confirm, and then maybe offer an idea or two as to why that might be happening, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what "Google's mobile emulator" is, because you didn't tell us, but FWIW it looks fine on a real Galaxy S4.

Comment: that's an excellent answer - thanks, tgies!  The emulator is part of the Developer Tools suite that's built into the Chrome browser. You can use it (supposedly) to preview the way any site will look on a variety of mobile devices.

Comment: Would still love to hear from anyone who knows how well the Dev Tools emulator works, though....thoughts?